# Accessing <FileInfo> and <DictionaryInfo> together in a heterogeneous list in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list,`ListofelementstoDelete`,that contain a mixture of `<FileInfo,DateTime>` key value pairs and `<DirectoryInfo,DateTime>` keyvalue pairs. My final goad is to delete them(files/folders) based on `DateTime` after sorting. But how do I handle both in a list? When I try to print it as follows, it gives error. Please help with the logic.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<FileSystemInfo,DateTime> elemenToDelete in ListofelementstoDelete)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemenToDelete.Key);
        }
```

And the error is

````
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.IO.FileInfo,System.DateTime]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.IO.FileSystemInfo,System.DateTime]'.
   at Program.Main(String[] args) ```
````

Comment: Your code seems like it should work.   
Can you add the errors you're getting?

Comment: What is the type of ListofelementstoDelete ?

Comment: Do you mean `DirectoryInfo` instead of `DictionaryInfo`?

Comment: ListOfelementsToDelete is a heterogeneous list of keyValuePair. It contains both <FileInfo,DateTime> and <DirectoryInfo,DateTime> objects. corresponding to files and folders.

Comment: Change `ListOfelementsToDelete` to be `List<KeyValuePair<FileSystemInfo,DateTime>>`. Then your foreach loop will work...

Comment: You can either separate the `KeyValuePair<FileInfo,DateTime>` and `KeyValuePair<DirectoryInfo,DateTime>` entries using `.OfType<...>()` and then handle each separately. Or you can `foreach(object elementToDelete ...)` and use conditionals/switch/pattern matching to determine what to do with the different types.

Comment: Thanks. I converted everything to FileSystemInfo and it worked.